# Segmentation Fault when getting the max of three numbers in Assembly x86

Tags: c, assembly

I am trying to get the max of three numbers using C to call a method in Assembly 32 bit AT & T. When the program runs, I get a segmentation fault(core dumped) error and cannot figure out why. My input has been a mix of positive/negative numbers and 1,2,3, both with the same error as a result.

Assembly

```
# %eax - first parameter
# %ecx - second parameter
# %edx - third parameter

.code32
.file "maxofthree.S"
.text 
.global maxofthree
.type maxofthree @function

maxofthree:
    pushl %ebp # old ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp # skip over
    movl 8(%ebp), %eax # grab first value
    movl 12(%ebp), %ecx # grab second value
    movl 16(%ebp), %edx # grab third value
    #test for first
    cmpl %ecx, %eax # compare first and second
    jl firstsmaller # first smaller than second, exit if
    cmpl %edx, %eax # compare first and third
    jl firstsmaller # first smaller than third, exit if
    leave # reset the stack pointer and pop the old base pointer
    ret # return since first > second and first > third
    firstsmaller:  # first smaller than second or third, resume comparisons
    #test for second and third against each other
    cmpl %edx, %ecx # compare second and third
    jg secondgreatest # second is greatest, so jump to end
    movl %eax, %edx # third is greatest, move third to eax
    leave # reset the stack pointer and pop the old base pointer
    ret # return third
    secondgreatest: # second > third
    movl %ecx, %eax #move second to eax
    leave # reset the stack pointer and pop the old base pointer
    ret # return second
```

C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
long int maxofthree(long int, long int, long int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
if (argc != 4) {
    printf("Missing command line arguments. Instructions to"
            " execute this  program:- .\a.out <num1> <num2> <num3>");
    return 0;
}

long int x = atoi(argv[1]);
long int y = atoi(argv[2]);
long int z = atoi(argv[3]);
printf("%ld\n", maxofthree(x, y, z)); // TODO change back to (x, y, z)
}
```

Comment: Don't remove the the code!  It makes the question for others to benefit from - useless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is causing a segmentation fault because it is trying to jump back to an invalid return address when the `ret` instruction is executed. This happens for all three different `ret` instructions.

The reason why it is occurring is because you don't pop the old base pointer before returning. A small change to the code will remove the fault. Change each `ret` instruction to:

```
leave
ret
```

The `leave` instruction will do the following:

```
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
```

Which will reset the stack pointer and pop the old base pointer that you saved.

Also, your comparisons are not doing what they are specified to do in the comments. When you do:

```
cmp %eax, %edx
jl  firstsmaller
```

The jump will happen when `%edx` is smaller than `%eax`. So you want the code be

```
cmpl %edx, %eax
jl   firstsmaller
```

which will jump when `%eax` is smaller than `%edx`, as specified in the comment.

Reference this [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow#Comparison_Instructions) for details on the `cmp` instruction in AT&T/GAS syntax.

Comment: I added your modifications and still receive the same error that there is a Segmentation Fault(core dumped). My code was updated above to reflect this.

Comment: I just compiled your updated code with `gcc -o maxofthree -m32 maxofthree.c maxofthree.s` with the call `maxofthree(1, 2, 3)` and got a result of 1 with no segmentation fault.

Comment: Also, this instruction `movl %eax, %edx` is still flipped. You want `movl %edx, %eax` to move the value of `%edx` into `%eax` to return.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pop `ebp` before returning from the function.
Also, `cmpl %eax, %ecx` compares `ecx` to `eax` not the other way. So the code

```
cmpl %eax, %ecx
jl firstsmaller
```

will jump if `ecx` is smaller than `eax`.